# Class is not a constructor in Laravel Mix

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, laravel-5.4, laravel-mix

I'm trying to access a class from a JS file by creating an instance in my blade.

Is there a way to access it outside of the js file?

Formula.js

```
class Formula() {
  initialize() {
   ...
  }
}
```

App.js

```
require('./modules/formulas/Formula');
```

formula.blade.php

```
 @section('page-specific-js')
  <script>
    var Formula = new Formula();
    Formula.initialize();
  </script>
@endsection
```

Webpack.mix.js

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.extract(['jquery', 'bootstrap-sass', 'moment', 'datatables-bootstrap', 'vue', 'axios']);
```

error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Formula is not a constructor
```

Comment: Are you exporting the class?